# Comparing Operator topologies-norm, strong and weak for a sobolev type linear operator.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

Another Stanford Qual question that has been bugging me.

Let $\mathcal{L}(L^2(\mathbb{R}))$ be the set of bounded linear operators on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Define $\Lambda_sf(\xi)=(1+|\xi|^2)^{is\backslash2}f(\xi)$, for $s \in \mathbb{R}$.

Consider the map $\Lambda:\mathbb{R}\to \mathcal{L}(L^2(\mathbb{R}))$ given by $\Lambda(s)=\Lambda_s$. Prove or disprove the following:

a) $\Lambda$ is continuous when $\mathcal{L}(L^2(\mathbb{R}))$ is given norm topology.

b)$\Lambda$ is continuous when $\mathcal{L}(L^2(\mathbb{R}))$ is given strong(operator) topology.

c)$\Lambda$ is continuous when $\mathcal{L}(L^2(\mathbb{R}))$ is given weak(operator) topology.

$\textbf{Thoughts}$:

1) $\Lambda_s$ is bounded in norm topology since $(1+|\xi|^2)^{is\backslash2}=\exp(\log(1+|\xi|^2)\frac{is}{2})$ which is in turn bounded by 1. Thus $||\Lambda_s f||\leq ||f||_2 $.

2) To prove continuity(or discontinuity) of $\Lambda$ it is enough to consider continuity at 0.

3) $||\Lambda_sf-\Lambda_0f||_2=||\left[\exp(\log(1+|\xi|^2)\frac{is}{2})-1\right]f||_2$

Now for a fixed $s>0$ we can choose $\xi$ so that $\log(1+|\xi|^2)\frac{s}{2}$ is a multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$, hence in a neighborhood of these points, $|\exp(\log(1+|\xi|^2)\frac{is}{2})-1| \geq \frac{1}{2}$. And hand wavely speaking, we can choose $f$ so that $f$ is supported on the union of these neighborhoods and $||f||_2=1$.

Thus we have  $||\Lambda_sf-\Lambda_0f||_2=||\left[\exp(\log(1+|\xi|^2)\frac{is}{2})-1\right]f||_2 \geq \frac{1}{2}$. Hence $\Lambda$ is not continuous in strong and norm topologies.

I think that the same type of example can be used to show that $\Lambda$ is not continuous in the weak operator topology.

All of this could be complete BS and I would appreciate if anyone could give me suggestions. Thanks in advance.

PS- The operator looks awful lot like the Fourier definition of Sobolev spaces except there is an $i$ there. Is there any sort of connection there, perhaps like heat and schrodinger's equation?

$\textbf{Edit}:$
As pointed out by amsmath that my counterexample works for the norm but not for strong and weak operator topologies. The reason being that the $f$ I was choosing depends on $s$ and for a fixed $f$ we can use Lebesgue dominated conv. theorem to show that it is actually continuous in the strong toplolgy.

Comment: "All of this could be complete BS" What is BS?

Comment: I meant everything I had done could all be bullshit :)

Comment: Your argument works for the norm topology, but I think it doesn't for the strong topology because your $f$ depends on $s$. In fact, for $f\in L^2(\Bbb R)$ you have$$\|\Lambda_s f- \Lambda_{s_0}f\|_2^2 = \int_{\Bbb R}\left|e^{\frac{is}2\log(1+|x|^2)}-e^{\frac{is_0}2\log(1+|x|^2)}\right|^2|f(x)|^2\,dx,$$which tends to zero by Lebesgue's majorized convergence theorem as $s\to s_0$.

Comment: That is of course true. So you are basically saying that it doesn't work for norm because we can change the $f$ for each s but not for the strong and weak.

Comment: No, your argument works for norm, but not for strong or weak. That's what I wrote before.

Comment: Sorry I flipped what I wanted to say. But I understand what you mean. Thanks for that. BTW do you know if there's any relation to Sobolev spaces($H^s$) which are defined without the $i$

Comment: They look similar, but they are fundamentally different. It's like comparing $e^t$ and $e^{it}$.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess it the difference is like the difference in heat kernel and the schrodinger's kernel